# Angular Schema Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angular-schema-form

I am completely new to Angular Schema forms and am trying to create some forms with it to display on my html pages. I would like to know how and where to place the `form content` and the `schema content` as defined in [this page](http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html). In what kind of files do I place these lines of code and how can I call the form to be displayed in my html pages?

**Form**

```
[
  "name",
  "email",
  {
    "key": "comment",
    "type": "textarea",
    "placeholder": "Make a comment"
  },
  {
    "type": "submit",
    "style": "btn-info",
    "title": "OK"
  }
]
```

**Schema**

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Comment",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "title": "Name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "title": "Email",
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^\\S+@\\S+$",
      "description": "Email will be used for evil."
    },
    "comment": {
      "title": "Comment",
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 20,
      "validationMessage": "Don't be greedy!"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "email",
    "comment"
  ]
}
```

Help in this regard with some detailed beginner level support guidelines will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to provide the schema and the instance data in a controller of your choice.

The documentation wiki provides a [basic example](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#basic-usage) where you should get all the necessary information.

Controller:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['schemaForm'])
       .controller('FormController', function($scope) {
  $scope.schema = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      name: { type: "string", minLength: 2, title: "Name", description: "Name or alias" },
      title: {
        type: "string",
        enum: ['dr','jr','sir','mrs','mr','NaN','dj']
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.form = [
    "*",
    {
      type: "submit",
      title: "Save"
    }
  ];

  $scope.model = {};
}
```

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="FormController">
    <form sf-schema="schema" sf-form="form" sf-model="model"></form>
</div>
```

Comment: So am I to place this code in a javascript file inside the controller and call it from my html page? (Bear with me, am extremely new to this)

Comment: Yep, place it in a JavaScript file and include it from a html template. I added the template code to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would also like to know what external resources I'll need to link in the html file's `<head>` section to get this working

Comment: You should really take a look at the docs, especially the [Installation section](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/tree/master#installation) in that case. The docs are really helpful and comprehensible.

Comment: @TaraWilfred Have you got it?

Comment: I switched to Bootstrap forms as it seemed much more easier. Anyway Thanks